# tinymce doesnt initiate editor again with dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a `div` that contains HTML contents that gets loaded dynamically. Every time I fetch a page using `$.ajax` I execute a function that transforms `.tinymce-basic` into TinyMCE textareas.

```
function on_page_load(){
    jQuery('.tinymce-basic').tinymce({
         theme: "modern"
    });
}
```

The first time the page loads all works great, tinymce loads correctly and functions just fine. However, when I reload the contents using `$.ajax` and call `on_page_load` to re-initiate TinyMCE, it never gets initiated. I have the dynamically loaded `<textarea class="tinymce-basic"></textarea>` just sitting there, and nothing happens.

Why doesn't TinyMCE re-initiate again? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to call `tinymce.remove(id)`  on every initiated instance. I assume when I attempted to re-initiate the same textarea ids it failed to do so because the ID already existed.

Comment: Finally something that works (tinymce.remove(id)....  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, 'textarea_id') didn't work for me.